# body runat="server" causing compilation error

Tags: asp.net

In a Master Page I have the following markup

```
<body id="body" runat="server">
```

I have set `runat="server"` because I need to be able to access the body element in code-behind.

I would now like to add a JavaScript function call to the `body onload` event, like this:

```
<body id="body" runat="server" onload="someJavaScriptFunction();">
```

However, this is giving my a compile error, with a message of "Cannot resolve symbol someJavaScriptFunction();". If I run the application I get an error telling me

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected
```

What is going on here? `onload` is a client-side event, so why does the ASP.NET compiler care about this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add this in the code behind;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     body.Attributes.Add("onload", "someJavaScriptFunction();");
}
```

Adding `runat="server"` to a tag makes it a server tag, even if it isn't one of the explicitly prefixed ones (e.g. `<asp:Panel />`). On server tags, any `onXXXX` event handlers handle the server-side events, not the client-side events (except for when "client" is explicitly called out, such as with OnClientClick for buttons).

Comment: OK, I can see how that would work - but why does adding runat="server" mean I need to use this approach?

Comment: I think because it's looking for the Body_SomeJavaScriptFunction method in the code behind, because you told it to "run at server" ?

Comment: Correct... I appended your answer Ian, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: No problem. I've hit my 200 rep points for the day so I guess I better get on with some work :)

Answer (score 3):

It is also an option to set:

```
<head>
  <script language="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() { someJavaScriptFunction(); }
  </script>
</head>
```

This is happening because ASP is trying to interpret the script inside the body tag as part of the code in the page.  As though it were C# / VB...

Comment: This doesn't answer the questions "What is going on here?" and "why does the ASP.NET compiler care about this?"

Comment: This is the approach that I went with in the end, in my scenario.